Did Loghain abandon the plan at Ostagar because the beacon was lit too late?
In the prologue of the 2009 video game Dragon Age: Origins, the battle plan at Ostagar was relatively simple. King Cailan led a contingent of his army in facing the invading darkspawn horde head-on, trapping them in a valley. Meanwhile, a small strike team was to ascend a nearby tower and light the beacon at its top. Loghain Mac Tir, commanding the rest (and the majority) of the army, waited off to the side. When Loghain saw the beacon lit, his role was to charge the darkspawn horde's flank, hopefully routing them.
Instead, when he saw the beacon lit, Loghain ordered the army to retreat. When the flanking attack never came, the horde eventually overran the forward contingent, killing King Cailan and most of his men, and continuing onward in their invasion.
I have read (but nowhere that provided sources) that Loghain's decision to betray and abandon his king was not premeditated, but rather came about because the beacon at the top of the tower was lit "too late."
What is the source of the idea that Loghain believed the beacon was lit too late to enact the intended battle plan? Does it come from dialog in the game, official tie-in or supplementary material, or developer commentary?
What justification, if any, is provided to support this belief? By what metric was the beacon lit too late? If Loghain could observe the status of the ongoing battle clearly enough to judge whether his flanking attack would be successful, why would he need a beacon to signal him at all?

I believe at some point he claims he wasn't going to throw away his men's lives trying and failing to save the king; whether he decided that before, during, or after the battle would be the rub.

I took to examining the game's script in the Dragon Age Toolset to get as close as I could to an answer.
First, it should be noted that the plan in question is presented as Loghain's plan:

Cailan: Fine. Speak your strategy. The Grey Wardens and I draw the darkspawn into charging our lines and then...?
Loghain: You will alert the tower to light the beacon, signaling my men to charge from cover.

Though, Cailan is the one who decides to send Grey Wardens to do so:

Loghain: I have a few men stationed there. It's not a dangerous task, but it is vital.
Cailan: Then we should send our best. Send Alistair and the new Grey Warden to make sure it's done.

Shortly after, when discussing the plan with Duncan and Alistair, Duncan confirms that the beacon is important, and (if the player asks) notes when to light it:

Duncan: This is by the king's personal request, Alistair. If the beacon is not lit, Loghain's men won't know when to charge.
[Later in the conversation, depending on dialog choices]
PC: When do we light the beacon?
Duncan: We will signal you when the time is right. Alistair will know what to look for.
PC: How much time do we have?
Duncan: The battle is about to begin. Once I leave, move quickly. You'll have less than an hour.

Despite Duncan's moderate urgency (saying to "move quickly" to be ready at the top of the tower in less than an hour), Alistair at least believes the actual important job will be done by Loghain's men, until he learns the tower is already overrun:

Soldier: The darkspawn came up through the lower chambers! They're everywhere! Most of our men are dead!
Alistair: Then we have to get to the beacon and light it ourselves!

Due to the unexpected darkspawn, it takes long enough to reach the top of the tower that Alistair thinks it might be too late:

Alistair: The beacon is over here! We've surely missed the signal... let's light it quickly before it's too late!

Given the context (and the reasonable narrative assumption that the story would indicate if it were otherwise), I think it's fair to believe that Alistair was correct that they missed the signal -- which means that objectively, the beacon was lit too late.
The other half of the question, of course, rides on whether that was a factor in Loghain's decision. Examining his dialog later in the game, there are a couple of possible exchanges discussing his betrayal:

Loghain: Warden, Cailan was Maric's son. Had there been any chance of reaching him at Ostagar, I would have fought to my last breath to save him.
Loghain: But was I to sacrifice thousands of other lives when I saw that hope was gone?


Loghain: What would you have me do? Cailan's was not the only life in my hands. Should I have sacrificed the entire army for his mistake?
Loghain: Do not imagine you can shame me with Cailan's death. He was Maric's son. My king. No one regrets his loss more than I do.

And later, after Loghain has lost (but not been killed, so he's still available to talk to, and has much less incentive to lie):

PC: You're a traitor and a coward.
Loghain: By all means, tell me again how I murdered Cailan. I find the topic inexhaustibly fascinating.
Loghain: There is no possibility, of course, the Cailan's poor judgment in leading the charge against my advice caused his death.
Loghain: Because he fell in battle, his part in the massacre must be excused, and because I survived, all responsibility must fall to me.

While it's clear that the decision to retreat was made in the moment, and therefore not pre-meditated in any way, there's also no indication whether the decision was actually influenced by the beacon's delay specifically.
I spent some additional time trying to see if any of the developers had commented on the matter, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything that touched on this exact question. That doesn't mean it's not out there, but with developers posting officially and unofficially on a variety of sites, some of which don't really exist anymore, going back almost fifteen years, I eventually had to give up the search.
It's not very satisfying, but the answer that leaves us with is that it's inconclusive whether the beacon being lit too late factored into Loghain's decision, but logically it may have contributed to him feeling like the battle was a lost cause, so it is at least a reasonable interpretation.
